# Remove all spaces from a string, that is only present before and after a delimitter

Tags: c#, vb.net

Ive a scenario to remove spaces from a string. But not all spaces. if so I can accomplish it simply using **replace** or **trim**. But the problem is to remove all spaces that is present before and after a specific delimitter in that string

For example consider the string

**Alex T Paul# John Tenor # Jeremy Cook  # Emerson #Peter**

Here there is lots of spaces in the string. But we need to replace all the spaces that is exists before and after the delimiter **#**

So the final text should be like

**Alex T Paul#John Tenor#Jeremy Cook#Emerson#Peter**

Comment: split the string by #, trim it and then concat it

Comment: Thanks buddy..  That will work.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using *regular expressions*:

```
  String source = "Alex T Paul# John Tenor # Jeremy Cook # Emerson #Peter";

  // Alex T Paul#John Tenor#Jeremy Cook#Emerson#Peter
  String result = Regex.Replace(source, @" *# *", "#");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var delimiter = '#';
var input = "Alex T Paul# John Tenor # Jeremy Cook # Emerson #Peter";

var parts = input.Split(delimiter);
var result = string.Join(delimiter.ToString(), parts.Select(s => s.Trim()));
```